# joining 4 tables

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I am new to this kind of relational type of database design. I just designed the database in this manner. However, I am quite confused on this `JOIN` of MySQL. What should be my query to join all this table. If you can see the table `users` is the reference of all the tables.

**users**

```
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
| users_id | users_level_id | users_status_id |
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
|        1 |              1 |               1 |
|        2 |              2 |               1 |
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
```

**users_credentials**

```
+----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| users_id | users_credential_username | users_credential_email      | users_credential_password  |
+----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
|        1 | super                     | super@gmail.com             | $5$e94e9e$vptscyHjm8rdX0j6 |
|        2 | admin                     | admin@gmail.com             | $5$fVuOmySyC0PttbiMn8in0k7 |
+----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

**users_level**

```
+----------------+-------------------------+
| users_level_id | users_level_description |
+----------------+-------------------------+
|              1 | Super Administrator     |
|              2 | Administrator           |
+----------------+-------------------------+
```

**users_status**

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+
| users_status_id | users_status_description |
+-----------------+--------------------------+
|               0 | Disabled                 |
|               1 | Enabled                  |
+-----------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: If you aren't familiar with `JOIN`s in SQL, please read a few articles about them. Two recommendations: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT u.*, uc.*, ul.*, us.*
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN users_credentials uc
    ON u.users_id = uc.users_id
INNER JOIN users_level ul
    ON u.users_level_id = ul.users_level_id
INNER JOIN users_status us
    ON u.users_status_id = us.users_status_id
```

Note the use `INNER JOIN`: this means that if a user does not have corresponing record on joined table it won't be shown; if you need to return every user even without matching record on related tables, change `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.

**EDITED after user comment:**
If you want to return just some column, define it as this example

```
SELECT uc.users_credential_username AS username, 
       uc.users_credential_email AS email, 
       uc.users_credential_password AS pwd, 
       ul.users_level_description AS level, 
       us.users_status_description AS status
```

Comment: Thanks Marco. Is it the best way to have this approach rather having `AS`?

Comment: @Defensor: pardon, I don't understand what do you mean with "*rather having AS*"...

Comment: I've seen some joins with a query like this `a.users_level_id AS level_id,` that's what I mean.

Comment: @Defensor: OK, maybe I guess: the use of AS is not needed in MySQL (nor in other databases), but if you use it is not wrong... it's just a matter of readability...

Comment: @Defensor: if you want to *rename* your fields, you have to explicitly write every of them in `SELECT` part and give them a name... if you need it it's OK; if you have fields with same name, it's worth doing it... otherwise it's not necessary IMHO.

Comment: Is that so. Thanks. Is there a way to except a column name to be included in the return? Rather than specifying each column name. In your example you use a wildcard that's why I received lots of column in the return.

Comment: @Defensor: no, you cannot keep a column away from a list: you can include it or not, this is the only way...

Comment: Thanks Marco. Really appreciated your time spent in assisting.

Answer (score 1):

I think this look like this :

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_credentials ON users.user_id = user_credential.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_level ON users.users_level_id = users_level.users_level_id
```

and so on..

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple query that will join all of them

```
select *
from users
  left join users_credentials
    on users_credentials.users_id = users.users_id
  left join users_level
    on users_level.users_level_id = users.users_level_id
  left join users_status
    on users_status.users_status_id = users.users_status_id
```

EDIT

if you want to fetch data from different tables
user this

```
select users.* , users_credentials.* , users_level.* , users_status.*
from users
  left join users_credentials
    on users_credentials.users_id = users.users_id
  left join users_level
    on users_level.users_level_id = users.users_level_id
  left join users_status
    on users_status.users_status_id = users.users_status_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this type of query....

```
SELECT c.*, l.*, s.*
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN users_credentials AS c ON (u.users_id = C.users_id)
INNER JOIN users_level AS l ON (u.users_level_id= l.users_level_id)
INNER JOIN users_status AS s ON (u.users_status_id= s.users_status_id)
```

Where you can specify the field what you want in .* ...

Answer (score 1):

Join is used to fetch data from normalized tables which have foreign key relation with the reference table.
For the above table with join you can fetch data among two tables with the help of reference table.
For example

```
Select * from users a JOIN users_credentials b 
ON a.user_id=b.user_id JOIN users_level c 
ON c.users_level_id=a.users_level_id 
where users_credential_username='super';
```

The result of this query will give you the detail like users_level_description for the user with users_credential_username=super.